# ffmpeg with libopenh264 Is blurry

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming

I am trying get live streaming using libopenh264 near the quality of libx264, but I am running into the quality issues. Here is a live stream standing still:

[image: no_blurry]

And here is image when there is fast movement:

[image: blurry]

The only documentation I've been able to find on options for libopenh264 is here: https://support.medialooks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000210192-H-264-encoding-options

Which give these values:

| Name | Default value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| slices | 0 | Set the number of slices, used in the parallelized encoding. This is only used when slice_mode is set to ‘fixed’ |
| slice_mode | auto | Set slice mode.Possible values:fixedrowmbautodyn |
| loopfilter | 1 | Enable loop filter, if set to 1. To disable set a value of 0. |
| max_nal_size | 0 | Set maximum NAL size in bytes. |
| allow_skip_frames | 0 | Allow skipping frames to hit the target bitrate if set to 1. |

But it seems options like slice_mode is incorrect, and playing around with options like slices and max_nal_size don't do anything. Here is my ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -y  -i pipe:0 -vf "scale=1920:1080:out_color_matrix=bt709" -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -c:v libopenh264 -b:v 9000k  -profile:v high -slices 10 -allow_skip_frames 1 -b_strategy 0 -maxrate 12000k -bufsize 9000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -g 120 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -ac 2 -ar 44100  -af afftdn -f tee -map 0 "[f=flv]${data.stream.invirtu_rtmp_broadcast_endpoint}?sign=${data.stream.invirtu_rtmp_broadcast_key}|[f=mp4]${escapedTempFilePath}"`;
```

Are there any other options I can be testing for  libopenh264 to improve the quality?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Most people use something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_ShadowPlay

Comment: @Gantendo yes but i am building an app that has to support those with and without Nvidia.