# h264_qsv is choppy when live streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-conversion, h.264

I am trying to do live streaming of video games using h264_qvs, but is choppy when compared to libx264. Here are some variations of the ffmpeg command I am running:

**Variation 1**

```
ffmpeg.exe -y  -hwaccel qsv -i pipe:0 -vf "hwdownload,format=nv12" -c:v h264_qsv -video_size 1920x1080 -preset veryfast  -global_quality 35 -look_ahead 0 -b:v 9000k -maxrate 12000k -bufsize 9000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -g 120 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -ac 2 -ar 44100  -af afftdn -f tee -map 0 "[f=flv]rtmp://endpoint.example.com|[f=mp4]C\:\\Users\\me\\savedFile.mp4"
```

**Variation 2: Moved the scale inside the vf**

```
ffmpeg.exe -y  -hwaccel qsv -i pipe:0 -vf "hwdownload,format=nv12,scale=1920:1080" -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryfast  -global_quality 35 -look_ahead 0 -b:v 9000k -maxrate 12000k -bufsize 9000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -g 120 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -ac 2 -ar 44100  -af afftdn -f tee -map 0 "[f=flv]rtmp://endpoint.example.com|[f=mp4]C\:\\Users\\me\\savedFile.mp4"
```

**Variation 3: Using scale_qsv and removed -pix_fmt yuv420p**

```
ffmpeg.exe -y  -hwaccel qsv -i pipe:0 -vf "hwdownload,format=nv12,vpp_qsv=framerate=60,scale_qsv=w=1920:height=1080" -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryfast  -global_quality 35 -look_ahead 0 -b:v 9000k -maxrate 12000k -bufsize 9000k  -r 60 -g 120 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -ac 2 -ar 44100  -af afftdn -f tee -map 0 "[f=flv]rtmp://endpoint.example.com|[f=mp4]C\:\\Users\\me\\savedFile.mp4"
```

**Variation 4:** Best Variation but still subpar to libx264, lag is 1 minute 30 seconds

```
ffmpeg.exe -y  -hwaccel qsv -i pipe:0 -vf "vpp_qsv=framerate=60,scale_qsv=w=1920:h=1080" -c:v h264_qsv  -preset veryfast  -global_quality 25 -look_ahead 1 -b:v 9000k -maxrate 12000k -bufsize 9000k  -g 120 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f tee -map 0 "[f=flv]rtmp://endpoint.example.com|[f=mp4]C\:\\Users\\me\\savedFile.mp4"
```

But no matter how I change it, the streaming is choppyl start/stop. What else shoud I be testing here for performance?

Comment: Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1807921/ffmpeg-with-libopenh264-is-blurry

Comment: @Gantendo yes but different encoder. So there are 5 encoders for h264 - libopenh264 by cisco, nvidia h264, amd h264, intel h264 and libx264 the most popular. This one is intels.